# Connect to Neo4j from a Node-Red flow and run a cypher query

Tags: neo4j, node-red

I am trying to access Neo4j from a Node-Red flow. 
I installed node-red-contrib-neo4j from the "Manage Palette" of Node-Red, from the browser interface (localhsot:1880)

However, i can't connect to the Neo4j database, since i get an HTTP error 401. In the neo4j node there are two fields : Name and URL. In addition, 
I can't add text to Cypher Query field.
What values should i provide?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

neo4j has [authentication](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/authentication/) enabled by default (which is more secure), and when it is enabled your REST requests must specify an [Authorization header](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/authentication/#http-api-authenticate-to-access-the-server). It does not look like the node-RED web user interface provides a way to specify headers.

If you want to keep authentication enabled, you may need to modify the node-RED source code to add support for user-specified headers.

Or, if a less secure setup is acceptable, you can disable neo4j authentication by setting the config property [dbms.security.auth_enabled](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.security.auth_enabled) to `false`.